# iPhone send data in facebook connect sdk

Tags: iphone, facebook, send

I have tried the  [facebook connect latest sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) with the DemoApp it comes with, when the user touches the publish button, it sends a message that is typed in a uiwebview [loaded from FB],

```
[_facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];
```

but I need to send some data from my app, not a typed message, so what can I use to send this strings from my app?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive found the answer,
is because the dialog method is for asking user to fill the form,

but to post the method used the [graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)! [which is not for graphs!!!]

the best example is this  [excellent tutorial](http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2)

;)